# Java : IllegalArgumentException in java.sql.Clob.getCharacterStream()

Tags: java, jdbc, ejb, clob, illegalargumentexception

I'm working on a application which contains EJB modules(an ear) in a separate jboss 4.2 server(yeah.. it's old) and the fornt end modules(.war) in another jboss 4.2 instance.

When a JDBC call is executed in and retrieving data from that result set,
I call the following method.

```
public static String clobToString(Clob clob) {
    StringBuilder strOut = new StringBuilder();
    if (null != clob) {
        String aux;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(clob.getCharacterStream());
            while ((aux = br.readLine()) != null) {
                strOut.append(aux);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }

    }
    return strOut.toString();
}
```

Then I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find method for
hash:6019464871547390790 available={8276829932266231084=public abstract void
java.sql.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(int,int,java.lang.String)
throws java.sql.SQLException, -4870182504746961607=public abstract
void java.sql.ResultSet.updateBlob(int,java.io.InputStream,long)
throws java.sql.SQLException, -986249454302332938=public abstract
java.math.BigDecimal java.sql.ResultSet.getBigDecimal(int,int) throws
java.sql.SQLException, -2603556243611874803=public abstract void
java.sql.ResultSet.updateAsciiStream(int,java.io.InputStream,int)
throws java.sql.SQLException, 6940864310164095298=public abstract void
java.sql.PreparedStatement.setObject(int,java.lang.Object,int) throws
java.sql.SQLException, -1839048404132746204=public abstract
java.io.InputStream java.sql.ResultSet.getBinaryStream(int) throws
java.sql.SQLException, 2412962096532620147=public abstract
java.net.URL java.sql.CallableStatement.getURL(int) throws
java.sql.SQLException, 3699478856524182484=public abstract int
java.sql.ResultSet.getInt(int) throws java.sql.SQLException,
-5709151791635973835=public abstract java.sql.Blob java.sql.ResultSet.getBlob(int) throws java.sql.SQLException,
1622039847402469151=public abstract java.sql.ResultSet
java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.getUDTs(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int[])
throws java.sql.SQLException, -2433480034363362194=public abstract
void java.sql.PreparedStatement.setNClob(int,java.sql.NClob) throws
java.sql.SQLException, -6485565124723778908=public abstract
java.net.URL jav
```